# Join exiting table with table variable

Tags: sql-server, join

I try to made inner join between table which exist into database called like 'Location' and also table variable called 'Locations'. You can see code below:

```
# CODE
    DECLARE @Locations TABLE (CityId int)
    INSERT INTO @Locations  values ('5'), ('2')
    SELECT *
    from @Locations
```

So first I create table variable with code above. But I have problem when I want to make inner join with other table called like 'Location'. Column CityId is have some value in integer format.In order to do this I try with this code:

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (CityId int)
INSERT INTO @Locations  values ('5'), ('2')
SELECT lo.CityId
FROM dbo.Location
INNER JOIN dbo.Location lo ON lo.CityId = @Locations
GO
```

But unfortunately this code is not work well.So can anybody help ho to fix this code with properly sintax and resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you had written inner join is wrong.
It should be like this. Try this out

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (CityId int)
INSERT INTO @Locations  values ('5'), ('2')
SELECT lo.CityId
FROM dbo.Location a
INNER JOIN @location lo ON lo.CityId = a.cityid
GO
```